# How can I make my enemy rotate to face a waypoint in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been following a tutorial on YouTube on how to make a tower defence game (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=beuoNuK2tbk) and in one of the episodes he teaches you how to make an enemy follow a pre made path. This worked just fine but I wanted to make my enemy rotate to allow it to face in the direction it was going. I tryed to use some of the code he showed in a later video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QKhn2kl9_8I) but it did not work as I kept getting an error, so I searched around a little and got what I thought was a solution.I do not know how to fix this code so if any of you can help that would be greatly appreciated. I am using Unity on a 3D project if that helps. This is  the error I keep getting "Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'UnityEngine.Transform' to 'UnityEngine.Quaternion' Tower Defence.CSharp    C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Tower Defence\Assets\Enemy.cs  27  Active"

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;

    public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed = 10f;
    public float smooth = 2f;

    private Transform target;
    private int wavepointIndex = 0;

    private Object waypoint;

    void Start()
    {
        target = Waypoints.points[0];

        InvokeRepeating("nextWaypoint", 0f, 0.5f);
    }


    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 dir = target.position - transform.position;
        transform.Translate(dir.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, target, Time.deltaTime * smooth);

        if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target.position) <= 0.4f)
        {
            GetNextWaypoint();
        }
    }

    void GetNextWaypoint()
    {
        if(wavepointIndex >= Waypoints.points.Length - 1)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            return;
        }

        wavepointIndex++;
        target = Waypoints.points[wavepointIndex];
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies at this line:  `Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, target, Time.deltaTime * smooth);`.

`Quaternion.Slerp` takes in `Quaternion`, `Quaternion` then `float` as parameter. You are currently passing in `Quaternion`, `Transform` and `float` to it.

`target` is defined as a `Transform` and you must use `target.rotation` to get the  `Quaternion`.

That line of code should be changed to :

```
 transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, target.rotation, Time.deltaTime * smooth);
```

Comment: That worked perfectly with removing the error. Is there any chance that you could help me make the enemy face the next waypoint. I have recorded a video that you can watch to see what I mean. The video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b5baqnWLcys

Comment: @StephenMynes I only came to fix your error.  **REPLACE** `transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, target.rotation, Time.deltaTime * smooth);` with `transform.LookAt(target);`. That should solve the rotation problem.

Comment: That was perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: @StephenMynes Please tick this as the answer if your problem is solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea would be to use `Transform.LookAt()`.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html

```
var lookPos = target.position - transform.position;
lookPos.y = 0;
var rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(lookPos);
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rotation, Time.deltaTime * smooth);
```

Comment: I tryed this but the enemy did not rotate enough some times, is there any way I could fix this?

Comment: Could this be, because your enemy is getting the new waypoint before the actual waypoint is reached? Tried to lower the minimal distance to `0.1f`?

Comment: It is still a little buggy but it will do for now, thank you very much :)